# Trigger local notification on applicationDidBecomeActive

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, notifications

I'm developing a alarm app by using UILocalNotification object. In my code, when alarming up and users click the notification panel, my app will show another view controller. I added codes in different life cycles below for satisfying the situation:

1. When alarming up, the app is in the foreground,
2. the app is in the background and users click notification panel to trigger up the app,
3. the app is killed and  users click notification panel to trigger up the app.

## When alarming up, if users click the app icon to trigger it instead of clicking notification panel, my function is not triggered in didReceiveLocalNotification. How to code to satisfy this situation?

---

### For triggering notification if the app was killed, iOS can check scheduled notifications automatically and response it in the launchOptions object

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions{

    [self registerNotification];    
    
    UILocalNotification *localNotification =
       [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];
    if (localNotification) {
        // Launch VideoVC
        application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
        [application presentLocalNotificationNow:localNotification];
    }
}
```

### For launch custom function when users click on notification

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application
didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification{

    [self launchMyFunction]
}
```

### If user click app icon instead of notification panel when alarms was triggered, didReceiveLocalNotification is not triggered

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
     
    // How to trigger the notification??????
}
```

Comment: you set the notification when a certain condition is met... you should just check if that condition is met in the applicationDidBecomeActive method and if the condition is met, call launchMyFunction

Comment: I've been thinking to check all my scheduled notifications in applicationDidBecomeActive:application method...  but not found the proper condition...

Answer (score 1):

I finally use badge number to solve it.
Thanks all members who replied my questions to inspire me.

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {

    if([UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber > 0){
        [self myFunction];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From didFinishLaunchingWithOptions you can call your didReceiveLocalNotification like below way.

```
if let notification:UILocalNotification = launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey] as? UILocalNotification {

self.application(application, didReceiveLocalNotification: notification)

}
```

This code is in swift, you could figure out in objective c.

Comment: I cannot get launchOptions in  applicationDidBecomeActive:application method

Comment: if the app is not killed and users click app icon to open it, the method didFinishLaunchingWithOptions will not be called

Comment: You can keep your local notification object in NSUserDefault to retrieve it at  applicationDidBecomeActive.

Comment: I've tried it. However, it doesn't know which notification was launched by iOS.